# How to create collection with fields/variables/indexes using mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, variables, nosql

I'm learning mongo from absolute scratch, and i can't for the hell of it figure out how to create a collection with predefined variables. I need to do that in order to have unique mails on my project. Any help would be very appreciated.

I'm trying to do a basic `CRUD`, and everything you see in the code is a lot of different tutorials combined into one, so far I'm able to create new users, and obtain a list of all of them, but in order to delete one or edit/update one I really need an unique attribute.

This is my code if it is useful:

```js
    const express= require ('express');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    const app = express();
    const cors = require('cors');
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const saltRounds=10;

    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.listen(3001,()=>{
        console.log("Welcome");
    });



    // CONEXION BASE DE DATOS
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.bs9d2.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    ,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(client=>{

        console.log('Bienvenido a database mongo');
        const db = client.db('ezbuy-database');
        const usersCollection = db.collection('users');

       

       
        /*Añade un usuario nuevo a la BD*/
        /*Falta ver como hacer datos unicos, pero no se como*/
         
        app.post('/newuser', (req, res) => {
            const userObject ={
            
                name: req.body.name,
                identification:req.body.identification,
                email:req.body.email,
                password:req.body.password,
                cellphone:req.body.cellphone,
                addedDate:req.body.addedDate,
                lastLoginDate:req.body.addedDate,
                role:req.body.role,
                speciality:req.body.speciality
               }
             ;
            bcrypt.hash(userObject.password,saltRounds,(err,hash) => {
                if(err){console.log(err)}
               userObject.password=hash;
               
               usersCollection.insertOne(userObject)
              .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                console.log("Dato Añadido a mongo  ");
                res.send('Usuario Creado');
              })
              .catch(error => console.error(error))
           
            })
            })
            
            /*Devuelve todos los usuarios creados*/
            app.get('/allusers', (req, res) => {
              db.collection("users").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result);
                res.send(result);
              });

              app.get('/userbyid',(req,res) =>{
                db.collection("users").findOne({})
              }
              )
            
              })

          
    }).catch(console.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm assuming that you are referring to a database schema with *create a collection with predefined variables*. MongoDB does not have a strict schema that prepopulates values with defaults. That is up to your application to handle.
   [Realm Schemas](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/document-schemas/)
2. After a document insert is completed you can read the inserted document id from the result with the `result.insertedId`.
   [MongoDB collection.insertOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.insertOne/)

```
usersCollection.insertOne(newUser)
  .then(result => console.log(`Successfully inserted user with _id: ${result.insertedId}`))
  .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to insert item: ${err}`))
```

to fetch that user document by id you can use `_id` in the filter.

```
usersCollection.findOne({_id: userId})
```

--
So in the case of a user collection the normal is normally to also have a unique value that a user can remember. *(email, username)*. In that case you need to create a unique index on the collection.
[MongoDB Unique Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/)

```
usersCollection.createIndex( { "email": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

The unique flag will take care that no user with a duplicate email address gets created and you can then query the user like the following.

```
usersCollection.findOne({email: emailAddress})
```

Comment: In the case of schemas there are libraries to help with that. First one I'd go for is mongoose. But since you are still learning I'd stay clear of those till you understand the underlying principles of mongoDB

Comment: usersCollection.createIndex( { "email": 1 }, { unique: true } )

This is exactly what i want to use, but how do i declare email? when i try to add this line of code i get an error, that createIndex is undefines.

Comment: @klalvarez Since you are using the db directly from mongodb maybe try adding that index through that gui.

Comment: @klalvarez But to answer that question, check if the usersCollection variable is set when you are trying to add the index.